# calculate average in a table using javascript

Tags: javascript

So the thing that i want to is to get the average of specific columns. 
I want to get the average of columns of PO1 up to PO9.
And i want to use javascript. So please help me guys. thanks

And here's my html table:

```
<table id="view_classlist" class="table table-striped table-bordered dataTable no-footer">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th><center>Student ID </i></center></th>
        <th><center>Name </i></center></th>
        <th><center>PO 1</center></th>
        <th><center>PO 2</center></th>
        <th><center>PO 3</center></th>
        <th><center>PO 4</center></th>
        <th><center>PO 5</center></th> 
        <th><center>PO 6</center></th> 
        <th><center>PO 7</center></th> 
        <th><center>PO 8</center></th> 
        <th><center>PO 9</center></th> 
    </tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
    <tr>          
        <td><center>111</center></td>
        <td><center>John</center></td>
        <td><center>1.1</center></td>
        <td><center>2.0</center></td>
        <td><center>3.0</center></td>
        <td><center>2.7</center></td>
        <td><center>1.9</center></td>
        <td><center>1.2</center></td>
        <td><center>1.1</center></td>
        <td><center>1.3</center></td>
        <td><center>1.2</center></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>          
        <td><center>112</center></td>
        <td><center>Mae</center></td>
        <td><center>1.2</center></td>
        <td><center>2.0</center></td>
        <td><center>1.2</center></td>
        <td><center>1.2</center></td>
        <td><center>1.3</center></td>
        <td><center>1.5</center></td>
        <td><center>1.4</center></td>
        <td><center>1.2</center></td>
        <td><center>3.0</center></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>          
        <td><center>113</center></td>
        <td><center>Jerry</center></td>
        <td><center>1.1</center></td>
        <td><center>1.2</center></td>
        <td><center>3.0</center></td>
        <td><center>2.7</center></td>
        <td><center>1.2</center></td>
        <td><center>1.6</center></td>
        <td><center>1.2</center></td>
        <td><center>2.3</center></td>
        <td><center>1.2</center></td>
    </tr>

    <tfoot>
        <td colspan="2"><center>Average</center></td>
        <td><center></center></td>
        <td><center></center></td>
        <td><center></center></td>
        <td><center></center></td>
        <td><center></center></td>
        <td><center></center></td>
        <td><center></center></td>
        <td><center></center></td>
        <td><center></center></td>
    </tfoot>
</tbody>
```

Comment: You won't get the codez here. Try yourself and if you really got stuck then come back.

Comment: Please don't use [`<center>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center), it's been deprecated for quite while, now. Use CSS (`td { text-align: center; }`) instead.

Comment: I have a library called [html5csv.js](https://github.com/DrPaulBrewer/html5csv) that will scrape your table into an array of arrays.  That data could then be processed by code you write to produce the averages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to do it:

```
var table = document.getElementById('view_classlist'),
  rows = table.getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0].getElementsByTagName('tr'),
  footer = table.getElementsByTagName('tfoot')[0];

// for each column that must be treated
for(var i=2; i<11; i++){
  var sum = numOfValues = 0;
  // add each row's value
  for(numOfValues=0, l=rows.length; numOfValues<l; numOfValues++){
    sum += parseFloat(
        rows[numOfValues].getElementsByTagName('td')[i]
          .getElementsByTagName('center')[0]
          .innerHTML
      );
  }

  // calculate the average
  var avg = sum / numOfValues;
  // insert it in the corresponding TD (rounded to 2 decimals)
  footer.getElementsByTagName('td')[i-1].innerHTML = Math.round(avg * 100) / 100;
}
```

#### JS Fiddle Demo

Comment: i tried your new code but it didn't work unfortunately, however the one you posted first did work if there are complete values in every column but the average won't work if there's an empty value in a column.

Comment: this is the error of the new code:
TypeError: rows[numOfValues].getElementsByTagName(...)[i].getElementsByTagName(...)[i] is undefined

Comment: @lewis Here is an updated version for when `<td>`s can be empty: http://jsfiddle.net/4h6w64d8/2/

Comment: i associated my table with php and it turns out that every time another row is added it will divide the number of rows and not the value. What to do?

Comment: @lewis I don't see what you mean, could you post a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) or a [pastebin](http://pastebin.com) with a table that your php outputs?

Comment: here's the sample output: http://imgur.com/zJuFSZm

and this is the code: http://pastebin.com/PWkVCk9T

thanks bro.

Answer (score 0):

I have a library called [html5csv.js](https://github.com/DrPaulBrewer/html5csv)  that can, among other things, scrape a table and add calculations in browser side JS.

First, let's clean up the table a bit to eliminate non-numeric data like `<center>` in the cells:

```
<table id="view_classlist" class="table table-striped table-bordered dataTable no-footer">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Student ID </i></th>
        <th>Name </i></th>
        <th>PO 1</th>
        <th>PO 2</th>
        <th>PO 3</th>
        <th>PO 4</th>
        <th>PO 5</th> 
        <th>PO 6</th> 
        <th>PO 7</th> 
        <th>PO 8</th> 
        <th>PO 9</th> 
    </tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
    <tr>          
        <td>111</td>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>1.1</td>
        <td>2.0</td>
        <td>3.0</td>
        <td>2.7</td>
        <td>1.9</td>
        <td>1.2</td>
        <td>1.1</td>
        <td>1.3</td>
        <td>1.2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>          
        <td>112</td>
        <td>Mae</td>
        <td>1.2</td>
        <td>2.0</td>
        <td>1.2</td>
        <td>1.2</td>
        <td>1.3</td>
        <td>1.5</td>
        <td>1.4</td>
        <td>1.2</td>
        <td>3.0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>          
        <td>113</td>
        <td>Jerry</td>
        <td>1.1</td>
        <td>1.2</td>
        <td>3.0</td>
        <td>2.7</td>
        <td>1.2</td>
        <td>1.6</td>
        <td>1.2</td>
        <td>2.3</td>
        <td>1.2</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Then to average by Task, we would add this JS with jQuery and html5csv.js loaded:

```
CSV.begin('#view_classlist')
   .call(function(next){
       var rows = this.data.rows; 
       var lCol=rows[0].length;
       var firstRow = 1;
       var lRow = this.data.rows.length;
       var colAvg = ['Average',''];
       for(var col=2; col<lCol; col++){
           colAvg[col] = 0.0;
           for(var row=1; row<lRow; row++)
               colAvg[col] += rows[row][col]/(lRow-1);
       }
       this.data.rows.push(colAvg);
     })
    .table("tableWithAvg")
    .go();
```

This begins with data scraped from the original table, calls a user defined function that adds a column average to the table, and then outputs a new table with id "tableWithAvg"

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/DrPaulBrewer/7b7uk5Lv/5/)

To average by student, we would want to add a column, and there is a CSV helper for that called `appendCol` in the [html5csv.js Wiki](https://github.com/DrPaulBrewer/html5csv/wiki).

The following works with the html5CSV.js library to average by student:

```
CSV.begin('#view_classlist')
   .appendCol("Avg", function(index, row){
       var sum = 0.0;
       for(var k in row){
           if (k.indexOf('PO')>=0) sum+=row[k];
       }
       return sum/9;
    }, true)
    .table("tableWithAvg")
    .go();
```

average by student [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/DrPaulBrewer/xp4a24f5/6/)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use jquery to grab the DOM element values and then add it up.

```
<html>
  <script>
    var total = 0;
    $('.data').each(function(){
      total += parseFloat((this).val());
    });
    console.log(total);
  </script>
  <body>
    <div class="data"><td>1</td></div>
    <div class="data"><td>2</td></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is a good start for adding up cells, but doesn't explain how to distinguish and handle data in different columns.